# Devextreme same lookup in two columns, how to avoid making the request twice?

Tags: devextreme-angular

I have two columns that have the same lookup, they send 2 requests to the same place in the API, how to call it only once and use it for both columns?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a http request with your service to API and cache the response in `new ArrayStore` (wrapped in dataSource object)

```
this.lookupsDataSource = new DataSource({ 
    store: new ArrayStore({
        data: //yourService.retrievedData 
            key: "Id", 
        })
    });
```

Then you could redeclare grids columns (if you use that configuration) or you could re-set datasource of both lookups to this new arrayStore)